# can't dismiss game center leaderboard

Tags: objective-c, iphone, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have a app, and i'm using GameCenter leaderboard.
but i can't dismiss the leaderboard:

this is my code :

```
-(void)showLeaderboard {


GKGameCenterViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

if (leaderboardController != NULL)
{
    leaderboardController.leaderboardIdentifier = @"Leaderboard";
    leaderboardController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
    leaderboardController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
}
}

- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)viewController
{
    NSLog(@"Close");
    UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have no idea what to do, :-

Comment: In which file is this code located? ViewController.m?

Answer (score 2):

Try dismissing your `viewController` in the code

Change your code like this

```
-(void)showLeaderBoard
{
    if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {
        leaderboardController.leaderboardIdentifier = @"Leaderboard";
        leaderboardController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
        leaderboardController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
        [self presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```